# Re-writing history in Git

Tags: git

I have removed 1.5 GB worth of binary blobs from a backup of a git repository using:
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Now when I compare the history/graph of the two repository the are now 100% identical. The bfg re-writes the history but is there any way to verify that the history is intact even though it might be look different?

And why does it look different? Does change the SHA values of commit generate a new graph?

Is it possible to run a log command for each repo that generates the commits for **all** branches that can then be diffed?

Comment: Yes, it does, changing of any component (filetree, commit time, etc) of a commit changes its SHA1, that's the whole point of SHA1 fingerprints.

Comment: So are there any way to verify that two "permutations" of a git graph are content wise identical?

Comment: Regarding the history verification. You could perform a `git log` with a custom format and thus compare any commit attributes you'd like to verify.

Comment: Can you point to an example?

Comment: run something like `git log --format='%s,%an,%ae,%ai,%cn,%ce,%ci'` in the old and new repos, save output to files, and then compare two files with plain old `diff` or `vimdiff` or any other diff tool.

Comment: what about git fsck to verify the integrity of the repo

Comment: You might want to add `%T` to the format as well, to verify that each commit that you think are identical both reference the same tree object.

Comment: Is it possible to run the log command for all branches with out having to check them out separately?

Answer (score 0):

The SHA of a commit is its unique identifier that is based on the exact contents of the commit. Part of the commit are the actual content, and metadata such as commit message, author/committer names *and* dates, and the id of the previous commit.

So when you change a single commit at the very beginning of the history, e.g. by removing a file, then the tree that stored that file before is recreated, causing a new hash for the tree, causing a new commit object with a new hash, causing all following commits to be recreated as well (the change is rippling through).

So, a single change recreates all commits in the following history. While this is unfortunate because it breaks all repositories that have the old history (that’s why you should avoid rebasing published changes in team projects), it also enforces integrity of your repository because commits are immutable.